# Scaleable Live Chat Architectures: Proxy-Managed v.s. Broker-Managed

Tags: websocket, architecture, chat, real-time, scale

I've done a lot of thinking about how to implement scaleable live-chat architectures., and I've come to the conclusion that there is two major ways to implement live-chat architectures: I call them Proxy-Managed and Broker-Managed.

Proxy-Managed:

- a proxy ensures all users in a chatroom receives messages by routing all users in a chatroom to the same WebSocket (WS) server in a pool of scaleable WS servers; one chatroom exists within a server selected by load balancing
- pros: is a system of minimal number of components
- diagram: [proxy-managed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAPS8.png)  (on imgur since not enough rep )

Broker-Managed:

- a broker ensures that all users, who may be routed to different WS servers, receive messages by uploading the message to all WS servers that handle the chatroom that the message is in; one chatroom exists across all servers
- pro: load is distributed based on the routing algorithm of the proxy
- diagram: [broker-managed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbBjS.png)

I'm creating this thread to discuss the architectures, not for a specific answer. I would like to see more points for and against either architecture.

Comment: Have you done any research into existing live-chat architectures (patterns, reference architectures, etc)?  It's not something I have ever looked into but there must surely be some.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try to find actual use cases of each. I've seen diagrams of the broker managed architecture before but I haven't researched any use cases yet.